# How to verify file/directory integrity when using SCP over SSH?

Tags: ssh, scp, checksum, integrity

I just copied a few directories and files using SCP from a SSH remote server. How can I check if the files were copied exactly and there were no errors or no files were skipped?

Comment: Attempt an `rsync`.  If it sees no changes to bring over, nothing was missed or badly copied.

Comment: You can go through this question:-https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253233/do-i-need-to-check-for-file-corruption-once-scp-is-done

Answer (score 2):

You can use `md5sum *  > chksum.txt` on the source side, transfer the `chksum.txt` file using `scp` and then on the destination side do:

```
md5sum -c chksum.txt
```